# Does multiple calls to LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<...> create a new file?

Tags: asp.net

In each asp.net core page, I make the following call:

```
new MyClass(LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<...>);
```

I am wondering whether that is the correct way or should I keep a singleton logger to be passed around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a correct usage.

The instance of the Logger that is created is independent of the output Sinks (file/console/debug/etc). Whatever sinks you have configured in your Startup will be used by the Logger instances that are created.

For Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1